# CSS numbering using nth-child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've a `div` and inside the `div` there is multiple `p` tags. I need to number them using css. The count of `p` tag may vary.

Using `:nth-child()` and `::before` I can do something like this

```css
div p:first-child::before {
  content: '1 '
}
div p:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '2 '
}
div p:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: '3 '
}
div p:nth-child(4)::before {
  content: '4 '
}
div p:nth-child(5)::before {
  content: '5 '
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</div>
```

If there is large amount of elements how can I implement it. Is there any way to child number in css inside `:nth-child()`, something like this.

```
div p:nth-child(n)::before {
  content: n
}
```

where  `n` is the child number. I know numbering can done using list, but I need to know is there any way to get child num inside the css selector.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters) by using `::before` (`:before` for IE8)  and `counter-reset/increment`

---

```css
div {
  counter-reset: number;
}
p {
  counter-increment: number;
}
p::before {
  content: counter(number)" ";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
  <p>abc</p>
</div>
```